# Is there a function to auto email answers added to a google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am setting up a google form and need the answers that are placed in the linked sheet to auto email those answers to a particular email address. So each time someone completes the form only the newly added answers get emailed.

I have it set up right now that any time the google sheet is updated it triggers an auto email with a link to the sheet in the email. This is working okay for now but would save so much time if that one notification email just had the answers in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post your code showing your attempt so far. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on writing a good question.

Comment: There are several tutorials about how to do this if you search "email google form responses" in a search engine, and even in YouTube. If you already have something setup, then the simplest thing you could do is just pull the [`namedValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) off of the event object and email yourself that instead of the URL (e.g. `JSON.stringify(e.namedValues)`).